# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. but the method is already post

Tags: php, laravel-8

[image]

i know it said that im suposed to use the method `POST` instead of `GET`. but i already changed the method into `POST`
here's the route

```
    Route::post('/OUT/cancelitem/{id}',[store::class,'outcancel']);
```

as to call it i do this

```
<a href="/OUT/cancelitem/{{ $itemp->id_autoinc }}"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
```

does anyone have a clue on why on earth is this happening?

Comment: When you click a link a GET request is made

Comment: so does that mean i have to use form instead of link?

Comment: Either that or ajax

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you came to the conclusion that your browser would create and send a POST request when clicking on a link? I’m not aware of any web browser that implements such behavior for anchor tags out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

As Musa Said, Link uses GET request instead of POST so it seems that i have to use either AJAX or form to submit a POST request